# Is it possible to override gradle from prompting error because ("." and "-") in the name of a variable? eg; name.dir (.dir not found) in task

Tags: gradle

The error message:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'telescope-master'.
> Cannot get property 'dir' on null object
```

**gradle.properties file**

```
classes.dir  = WebContent/WEB-INF/classes  
webContent.dir  = WebContent  
template.dir  = hdm/template  
javascript.dir  = hdm/function  
javascript4.0.2.dir  = hdm/function/4.0.2       
datamodel.dir  = hdm/datamodel  
certificate.dir  = certificate
```

**build.gradle file**

```
Properties extFile = new Properties()
extFile.load(new FileInputStream('gradle.properties'))

task FirmwareMatch(type: Zip) {
    from ("${extFile.javascript.dir}")
    include 'factoryResetOnFirmwareMatch.*'
    archiveName 'factoryResetOnFirmwareMatch.zip'
    destinationDir file('dist/hdm/function')
}
```

So basically if I remove the "." from .dir on both files it would work. But is there any way to over ride it?

Also how can I display actual date when using ${TODAY} in gradle.

Comment: You'll want to stick to one question at a time, so I'd suggest posting the date question separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problematic expression is:

```
extFile.javascript.dir
```

If we break that into how Groovy will interpret it:

```
extFile.getProperty('javascript').getProperty('dir')
```

You want Groovy to interpret it as:

```
extFile.getProperty('javascript.dir')
```

Besides directly calling `getProperty`, here are a couple Groovy options:

```
extFile.'javascript.dir'
extFile['javascript.dir']
```

Additionally, assuming your `gradle.properties` file is either in your project root (generally as a sibling to the `build.gradle`) or in your `GRADLE_HOME` directory (i.e. `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`) it will be automatically loaded by Gradle and all properties available as project properties.

So you can remove all of your properties parsing code and just do the following:

```
project.getProperty('javascript.dir')
// or
project.'javascript.dir'
// or
project['javascript.dir']
```

If you want to protect against those properties not being set, and are on Gradle 2.13 or higher, you can use `findProperty` instead of `getProperty` which will return `null` instead of throwing an exception.